# Updating Existing Object in Firebase with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been having trouble saving an object pulled in from Firebase.  I want to grab the value of 'cardAmount', add to it and save it.  But it keeps giving me trouble about it not being ale to convert a number to a string.  I think I might be hung up on modifying the data structure wrong, but I've been stuck on this for a little while - can anyone give me some guidance on how to edit a single Child Snapshot in Firebase as I need it?

```
let sevenDayOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Seven Day: $31", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: (FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser?.uid)!)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let cardAmount = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "cardAmount").value as! Float
            let newAmount = cardAmount + 31
            let newAmountString = String(format:"%.2f", newAmount)
            snapshot.setValue(newAmountString, forKeyPath: snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "cardAmount").value as! String)
            print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "cardAmount").value as! Float) /*<---- Prints Optional(30.5)*/

        })
    })
```

I'm sure it's probably something simple, but it's also something that eludes me at the moment.  Relatively new to Firebase and Swift so its been a bit of a challenge wrestling with it at times.

Thanks!

Comment: there is **runTransactionBlock**. Or you can use **updateChildValues** method

Comment: updateChildValues worked perfectly!  Submitting answer.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who come across this and have trouble in the future - the answer came from the `updateChildValues` method that Firebase offers:

```
let sevenDayOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Seven Day: $31", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: (FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser?.uid)!)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let cardAmount = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "cardAmount").value as! Float
            let newAmount = cardAmount + 31
            let newAmountString = String(format:"%.2f", newAmount)
            ref.updateChildValues(["cardAmount":newAmountString])/*<------ CRITICAL*/
        })
    })
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ref.child("yourKey").child("yourKey").updateChildValues(["cardAmount": yourNewCardAmount])
```

This worked for me. Hope will help someone...